# Get last two characters from char array elements

Tags: arrays, c, char

Trying to print the array elements, like below

```
typedef struct Info
{
char MacAdd[2];                      
} Info;

char MAC[100];

sprintf(MAC, "%x:%x%c", Info->MacAdd[0], Info->MacAdd[1],'\0');

printf("MAC %s",MAC);
```

Got output is  --> ffffff98:ffffffa4

How can get output like ---> 98:a4

Comment: Redeclare `MacAdd` as `unsigned`.

Comment: How is `Info->MacAdd` defined? from output given it looks like these are signed integers with negative values? You don't need to null-terminate, by the way, `sprintf` does so anyway (unless you *want* a duplicate null character). Still good that you think of...

Comment: You don't need `%c` or `'\0'` in your `sprintf` call. `sprintf` takes care of that for you.

Comment: To always get two characters printed even for single-digit values try `%.2x` or `%02x`.

Comment: updated the question, can you please check

Answer (score 1):

The `MacAdd` array in your `Info` structure is declared as an array of `char`.  But `char` is usually a *signed* type.

When you call `printf`, certain "default argument conversions" take place.  Among other things, type `char` is promoted to `int`.  And since 0x98 as a signed char is actually negative (it's -104), it is automatically *sign extended* when that happens -- that's where the extra `ff`'s come from.  The value `ffffff98` is the 32-bit signed version of -104, so the value has been preserved.

There are at least three ways to fix this, in what I'd consider the order of most to least attractive:

1. Redeclare the `MacAdd` array as an array of `unsigned char`.
2. Change the printf format to `"%hhx:%hhx"`.  The `hh` tells `printf` that your value was originally a `char`, and this asks `printf` to undo the promotion and, in effect, strip the unwanted `ff`'s back off.
3. Change the call to `sprintf(MAC, "%x:%x", Info->MacAdd[0] & 0xff, Info->MacAdd[1] & 0xff);`

As @Aconcagua points out in a comment, once you get rid of the `ff`'s, you will probably also want to tweak your printf format a little bit more, to take care of single-digit addresses.

---

Footnote: Solution 3 above is reasonably terrible, and I wouldn't seriously recommend it.  It's what we used to use back in the days of Ritchie's original C compiler, when neither `unsigned char` nor `%hhx` had been invented yet.

Comment: _usually a signed type_ No. On many systems it is unsigned. It can be signed yes.

Comment: Additionally: Most compilers offer an option to control signedness explicitly...

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 I'm not going to get into a long argument about it, and I'm only partly serious when I say this, but: for 100% of the compilers I have used, and more importantly, for 100% of the compilers that GNK has used, type `char` is in fact signed.  So I stand by that word "usually". :-)

Comment: @SteveSummit This depends often on the system and not the compiler. GCC on AMD64 uses signed, GCC on ARM uses unsigned.